# Viewport clipping noise(?) with a huge object

Tags: objects, 3d-view, scale

I'm trying to work with a really large object (XYZ approx. 8,000x7,000x8,000 meters) and the viewport seems to have trouble showing just the things facing me at the corners. It's like things become partially transparent at this scale when they're "near" each other (see animated gif, it's hard to describe). Is there any way to fix this and get a clean display? I want to work at 1:1 scale, should I not at this size?

[image]

Comment: It looks like this pushes the limits of camera clipping.  It appears camera clipping has some undefined behavior above 10000m.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with very large or very small objects it is likely that you run into problems with lack of precision in the depth buffer. 3d engines cannot precisely determine which objects are in front of others, creating z-figthing. The fix is to adjust the **Clip Range** so that it encompasses your scene, no more, no less.

Select the camera, then in the camera section of the properties window set clip start and clip end.

[image]

To visualize the clip range, enable Viewport Display > Show > Limits

[image]

Comment: Thanks, adjusting Clip Start fixed it. Doesn't affect my renders because the camera default Clip Start is higher than the viewport's.

Comment: The detph buffer is limited. To avoid imprecision such as Z fighting use it to fit your scene (and camera distance).